# Google App Engine - http request/response

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, timeout, httprequest, urlconnection

I have a Java web app hosted on Google App Engine (GAE). The User clicks on a button and he gets a data table with 100 rows. At the bottom of the page, there is a "Make Web service calls" button. Clicking on that, the application will take one row at a time and make a third party web-service call using the URLConnection class. That part is working fine.

However, since there is a 60 second limit to the HttpRequest/Response cycle, all the 100 transactions don't go through as the timeout happens around row 50 or so.

How do I create a loop and send the Web service calls without the User having to click on the 'Make Webservice calls' more than once?

Is there a way to stop the loop before 60 seconds and then start again without committing the HttpResponse? (I don't want to use asynchronous Google backend).

Also, does GAE support file upload (to get the 100 rows from a file instead of a database)

Thank you.

Adding some code as per the comments:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(35000);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodedCredentials);

                // Send post request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(submitRequest);
```

Comment: Can you post the current codes which do the http connections?

Comment: @DevilingMaster updated with the code

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what happens with the results of these calls.

If results are not returned to a UI, there is no need to block it. You can use Tasks API to create 100 tasks and return a response to a user. This will take a few seconds at most. The additional benefit is that you can make up to 10 calls in parallel by using tasks.

If results have to be returned to a user, you can still use up to 10 threads to process as many requests in parallel as possible. Hopefully, this will bring your time under 1 minute, but you cannot guarantee it since you depend on responses from third-party resources which maybe unavailable at the moment. You will have to implement your own retry mechanism.

Also note that users are not accustomed to waiting for several minutes for a website to respond. You may consider a different approach when a user is notified after the last request is processed without blocking your client code.

And yes, you can load data from files on App Engine.

Comment: yes, I need to show the results to the User. Do you have links to any examples that do the Tasks in threads? Aren't tasks only for Backend programs? Can GAE Frontend also use tasks?

Comment: Tasks by default target your regular (frontend) instances. You have to specify the backend if you want them executed there. As for the threads, you have to do nothing if you use tasks - just configure your app to be thread-safe, and configure the queue (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [asynchronous urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService#fetchAsync(com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest)) calls:

```
LinkedList<Future<HttpResponse>> futures;

// Start all the request
for (Url url : urls) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
    request.setPayload(...)
    futures.add(urlfetchservice.fetchAsync(request);
}

// Collect all the results
for (Future<HttpResponse> future : futures) {
    HttpResponse response = future.get()
    // Do something with future
}
```

Comment: My app is a Java application (not Python)

Comment: @user972391- GAE Java API also has an [asynchronous API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService#fetchAsync(com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest)).